# Unable to exceute the C code

Tags: c

```
int  main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        FILE *fp, *fp1, *fp2;
        char line[200], temp[50], prev_het[5], curr_het[5], pdb_id[5], conneected_residues[10000], pres_name[4], pres_no[9], curr_temp[5], lig_atom[6], is_reesidue_present[10], curr_het_num[9], prev_het_num[9], chain_prot[2], chain_lig[2]];
        p_atom *front, *present;

        double het_x, het_y, het_z, dist;
        int flag, comma_indicator, no_of_het_atoms = 0, nmr_flag = 0, prot_ccount =0, connected_het = 0, connected_prot = 0, atom_flag = 0;

        front = present = NULL;
        prev_het[0] = curr_het[0] = '\0';
        fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

        if(fp == NULL)if(fp == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error in opening %s file",argv[1]);
            exit (0);
        }
```

Hi all,
This is part of my  C Code. I am unable to understand how to execute this code as it is giving error as mentioned below:

"Error in opening (null) file"

May anyone please help me out

Comment: how are you running the program? You have to give filename in command line argument to run this.

Comment: You didn't pass any arguments on the command line.

Comment: Am i not running it properly...

Comment: I gave  ./program_name....What else should i add

Comment: Laxmi, as per my answer, it needs a file name as well, such as `./program_name myfile.txt`. You probably should be reading the answers rather than trying to nut it out in the comments section.

Comment: What's this? `if(fp == NULL)if(fp == NULL)`

Comment: Sorry by mistake it has come twice. I am not able to get it quickly as i am new to this coding. Thanks for ur response.

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting the error:

```
Error in opening (null) file
```

then it's usually because you've provided a NULL pointer to `fopen()` though, since this is technically undefined behaviour, all bets are off as to what will *actually* happen.

Since the parameter to `fopen()` is `argv[1]`, it's almost certainly because you haven't run the program with an argument.

In other words, you're doing `myprog` rather than `myprog myfile`, meaning that the first argument will be `NULL` (as is required by the standard).

In any case, you should be programming defensively to catch that particular problem, with something like:

```
if (argc < 2) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Not enough parameters\n");
    return 1;
}

FILE *fp = fopen (argv[1]);
if (fp == NULL) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Cannot open file\n");
    return 1;
}
:
// Can probably assume it's okay now.
:
fclose (fp);
return 0;
```

---

You may also want to look into:

```
if(fp == NULL)if(fp == NULL)
```

I'm pretty certain (unless you're using threads) that, if it's `NULL` the first time, it will be `NULL` the second time as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looking from error, I think `argv[1]` was empty or null. Please check if you have to specify file-name on command line.